# CSS Modal Window Issue inside multiple divs

Tags: css, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a Modal Window which is spaning accross the entire application on the web page.

Application consists of **deep level divs** nested one after the other.
For eg: panels > panel > panel-detail > card > card-content

I wish to create a Modal Component for each card but all of them should be spanning accross the application.

**Requirement**
[image]

**Actual**
[image]

Below is my CSS:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

My HTML Structure for modal is:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>Card 1 Modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consider the element with class="modal" wrapped in the nested divs.

How shall I write my CSS so as the modal in Card 1 appears to be spanning accross the entire application?

Would it be a good idea to put the modal component outside the nested divs?

Comment: maybe you could set `position: inherit;` for the modal

Comment: because position of modal is absolute.

Comment: @MohammadAghayari no it isn't. It's `fixed`

Comment: When I recreate your layout the modal works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/12q1y6y7/. Can you create a [MCVE] showing the issue?

Comment: Post all of the HTML and CSS that you are using to display all the divs involved.  At the moment, we can't see what divs surround your modal div.

Comment: I post the answer. I hope it can be useful. try my answer.

Comment: Note also, if you want your modal div to take up 100% width, then ok, you can use fixed position and it will take up full width and not look like a modal window.  If you want it centred and not taking up full width, you will need to set width less than 100%, don't use position:fixed, and set left and right margins to auto, i.e. margin: 100px auto 100px auto; or classically margin: 0 auto; (top and bottom margin 0, left and right margin to auto).

Comment: The parent container of the modal window is positioned absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to display something as modal, it means it need to use `position: absolute`, and the effect of putting a shadow over all other divs I made it using RGBA function, which is a common rgb color plus opacity.

Take a look at this example:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content1{
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.content2{
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.content3{
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 justify-content: center;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
 align-self: center;
 background-color: red;
 margin: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #888;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100px;
}

#other {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
   margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content1">
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
  </div>
  <div class="content3">
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <p>Card 1 Modal</p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="other">
  something else
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why? There is something I'm missing in this case. Maybe you need to call this div when you click on a particular div, is it the case?

Comment: The modal has come above the 3 cards but is not coming over it's container.

Comment: The CSS of the container of the modal is having following properties {display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px 25px;
    -webkit-transition: display 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: display 0.8s;
    transition: display 0.8s;
    border-top: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;}

Comment: I think I understood what you are trying, take a look, I've modified my snippet. Now the modal content is shown into its parent, you just need to accomodate it like you prefer

Comment: I've added one more div outside from the main just to be sure that the modal div is showing only inside its parent.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be necessary to take the modal divs outside of the nested divs if their `position` is `fixed`:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
/*     background-color: rgb(0,0,0); */
}

.modal-open {
  display: block;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Card 1 Modal</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Card 2 Modal</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="modal modal-open">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Card 3 Modal</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this style. I will be fixed the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/12q1y6y7/1/

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    position:inherit;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

.third {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  postition: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mohammad, but writing the position property twice; is as good as writing position:inherit; once

Comment: this didnt work... my parent container of the modal window is having absolute positioning,

Comment: Did you check the link?